# Is it good practice to delete Default Web Site in IIS?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

I can't found nothing recent on the web about if deleting `Default Web Site` in `IIS` is a good practice, i'm using `IIS v10` and as in `wwwroot` i have each website inside it's own folder in `IIS` i've just created a website for each of them..

So i'm just not using the `Default Web Site` and i was wondering if will it cause any problem if i will delete it (for now i've just disabled it but seeing it in the list is a bit triggering), about deleting or keeping the `Default Web Site` i just found an article from 2001 so i would know something more recent about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can safely delete the `Default Web Site` in IIS Manager, even though delete the files under the `wwwroot`. And it should be a good practice to do that to avoid some unexpected web accesses or attack.

And the `Default Web Site` in IIS Manager, even though the files under the `wwwroot`, is used for the first validation of IIS installation.

More, the `Default Web Site` will take the default port 80 if not disabled/deleted.

So, please go ahead to delete it.

Comment: Is it also safe to delete `DefaultAppPool`?

Comment: Yes, but please confirm that there has no web application hosted under the pool before you delete it. otherwise, you cannot do that.